# Converting and Passing Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I basically want to pass this array of data I'm reading to diffent functions and eventually plot it.

The array contains a 32 bit word of '1's and '0's, I then want to add these individual bits together to see where my data spikes. So in other words if I add "0100" to "0110" I get "0210" - which is probably easier done with separate bins and plotting.

At the moment I'm just getting garbage out.

```
void binary(int convert, int* dat) {
  bitset<32> bits(convert);
  //cout << bits.to_string() << endl;
  char data[32];

  for(unsigned i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    data[i] = bits[i];
  }
  for(unsigned i = 32; i; --i) {
    dat[i] = (int(data[i-1]))+dat[i];
  }
}


void SerDi() {
  int dat[32];
  cout << "    Reading data from memory..." << endl;
  ValVector< uint32_t> data=hw.getNode("SerDi.RAM").readBlock(8);
  hw.dispatch();
  cout << data[0]<<endl;
  cout << data[1]<<endl;
  for (unsigned i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
    binary(data[i], dat);
  }
  cout << dat[7] << endl;
  graph(dat); //passes the array to a place where I can plot the graph
}
```

Comment: "*So in other words if I add "0100" to "0110" I get "0210"*"  Of course this will never work so long as you are using binary digits (base 2) for the accumulation.  You'll need a `vector<unsigned>` or similar for the accumulation.

Comment: Ok I tried a "vector <unsigned> dat" but I come up with a segmentation error when I run it.

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
int dat[32];
```

But in convert you have `i = 32` and `dat[i]` That will access something outside of the array and bad things will happen.

Also that is not initialized. Add a memset/loop somewhere to make `dat` initially `0`.

Comment: flz@ If you still have a bug, try debugging. Limit the loop to 0, 1, 2 iterations print everything and verify it works as expected.